# animating (sliding) a div sideways using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a div from left. I was studying from one of the tutorials on the web but for some reason the query is not working. I can't see why. Is there something wrong with the query?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jquery practice page</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ?
      -$lefty.outerWidth() :
      0
    });
  });
  });

</script>

<style type="text/css">


.slide {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: #ffc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.slide .inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 338px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: #4c5;
  color: #333;
  }

#slidebottom .inner{
    display:none;
}

.slide button {
  margin: .7em 0 0 .7em;
}

</style>

    </head>
    <body>

<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
  <button>slide it</button>
  <div class="inner">This is supposed to slide in from the left</div>
</div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Above is the entire thing. I cannot seem to be able to find the mistake. Can someone help me?

Comment: You are never making the div visible. It's display property is set to none. Also your jQuery CSS selectors are incorrect.

Comment: @Jivings I messed up the CSS trying to do something. Corrected most of them but just couldn't find those two! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mistakes in your demo:

$('#slideleft button') is not correct. It should be $('#slidebottom button').

Should remove this below css or you would not see anything

```
#slidebottom .inner{
    display:none;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8FLZC/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are three things to edit in your code:

**1. wrong selector:**
change

```
$('#slideleft button').click(function() {
```

to

```
$('#slidebottom button').click(function() {
```

**2. element needs to be visible**:
You hide the sliding element in your css. So you need make it visible again, before sliding it in.

```
$lefty.animate({
    left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0,
    opacity: "show"
});
```

**3. element is at the wrong place**
You also need to moved the sliding div to the left, so it will slide in on the first button press:

```
slide .inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: -350px;
```

See this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ax4AC/2/